# Unable to get text from html element for Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am using selenium with Java. I am unable to get text from html element that is a combobox. Every time I am getting blank text for the selected value in combobox.

Below is my html structure for combobox.

```
<ul id="servicetype-cave" class="z-combobox-content" style="height: auto;     width: auto;">
    <li id="zk_comp_140" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_141" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_142" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_143" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_144" class="z-comboitem z-comboitem-selected">
        <span class="z-comboitem-image"/>
        <span class="z-comboitem-text">Bill Grouping Service</span>
    </li>
    <li id="zk_comp_145" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_146" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_147" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_148" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_149" class="z-comboitem">
    <li id="zk_comp_150" class="z-comboitem">
</ul>
```

I have used below xpath for the element

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//ul[@id='servicetype-cave']/li[contains(@class,'z-comboitem-selected')]/span[@class='z-comboitem-text']")
public WebElement selectedServiceName;

public void selectService {
// Selecting an option from dropdown
WebElement tempEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[2])[3]"));
commonFunctions.clickElement(tempEle);
String strtemp = selectedServiceName.getText();
System.out.println("Selected Service: " + strtemp);
}
```

Please help.

TIA.

Comment: Show code you use to get text

Comment: @Andersson: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suggesting you try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#servicetype-cave li.z-comboitem-selected span.z-comboitem-text"));
```

or

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#servicetype-cave li.z-comboitem.z-comboitem-selected span:nth-child(2)"));
```

Now use `.getText()` to getting the text as below :

```
el.getText();
```

If unfortunately `.getText()` does not work try using `.getAttribute("textContent")` as below :

```
el.getAttribute("textContent");
```

or try using `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` as below :

```
el.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Hope it works..:)

Comment: Treid with getAttribute("textContent"). It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @BhargavRaval it's may be designing issue that's why you are not getting by using `.getText()`...:)

Comment: Okkay. Cool. Thanks very much Buddy. Accepted... :)

Answer (score 0):

`@FindBy` is eager internalization. That means it initializes when `Page` [object](http://www.assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/) creates. You should get value of combo-box after some preconditions, I assume. So make it use `lazy initialization`. Invoke following code just in place where you actually need it

```
findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='servicetype-cave']/li[contains(@class,'z-comboitem-selected')]/span[@class='z-comboitem-text']"));
```